# Running Wicket the first time

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wicket

I am having issues with the [Wicket GAE sample application](https://github.com/martin-g/wicket-gae-demo),

The issues is that some import cannot be resolved:

```
import org.apache.wicket.page.PersistentPageManager; // This one 
import org.apache.wicket.util.io.IObjectStreamFactory; // and this cannot be resolved

@Override
    public void init()
    {
        super.init();
        getResourceSettings().setResourcePollFrequency(null);


        WicketObjects.setObjectStreamFactory(new IObjectStreamFactory() {

            @Override
            public ObjectInputStream newObjectInputStream(InputStream in)
                    throws IOException {
                return new ObjectInputStream(in);
            }

            @Override
            public ObjectOutputStream newObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out)
                    throws IOException {
                return new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            }

        });

        setPageManagerProvider(new DefaultPageManagerProvider(this) {

            public IPageManager get(IPageManagerContext pageManagerContext)
            {
                IDataStore dataStore = new HttpSessionDataStore(pageManagerContext, new PageNumberEvictionStrategy(10));
                IPageStore pageStore = new DefaultPageStore(getName(), dataStore,
                        getCacheSize());
                return new PersistentPageManager(getName(), pageStore, pageManagerContext);

            }
        });

        // add your configuration here
    }
```

Also, the `getCacheSize()` method cannot be found, I am using Wicket version, 1.5-SNAPSHOT as used in the demo app, but I tried other later versions too but still cannot be resolved, how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This classes and methods were introduced only in *RC* versions (or earlier release versions) and removed from *1.5 release*

So, you can download one of the *RC* packages or migrate to *1.5 version*.

To migrate, you should:

1. Remove code `WicketObjects.setObjectStreamFactory...`. This will be replaced by defining serializer for `pageStore`. See [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5#MigrationtoWicket1.5-%28RC5%29Pluggableserialization) migration section.
2. Override `DefaultPageManagerProvider`'s `get` method as follows:

```
@Override
public IPageManager get(IPageManagerContext context)
{
    IDataStore dataStore = new HttpSessionDataStore(context, 
                                             new PageNumberEvictionStrategy(10));
    IPageStore pageStore = new DefaultPageStore ( 
                                     new JavaSerializer ( getName() ), dataStore,
                                     getStoreSettings().getInmemoryCacheSize());
    return new PageStoreManager(application.getName(), pageStore,
                                                           context);
}
```

For further migrations you should check wicket [migration guides](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migrations).